# Could not find artifact > org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.5.1-SNAPSHOT in jboss-public-repository-group

Tags: maven

In an attempt to do some *cleaning*, I seem to have botched something with my maven setup.  I have a single profile defined and enabled in my settings.xml, according to the long-standing directions at https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users.

Nevertheless, when I try to build a project, like so:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -U -e
```

I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.5.1-SNAPSHOT in jboss-public-repository-group (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/) -> [Help 1]
>      org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.5.1-SNAPSHOT in jboss-public-repository-group (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/)

I *think* this started sometime today, and I actually have a variety of different versions of this plugin in an archived local repo, but for some reason, I can't seem to download *any* versions of this plugin now.

Comment: Did you try a maven update?

Comment: Why do you use -SNAPSHOT version? In the meantime the final release of version 3.5.1 is out and is available in [Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.maven.plugins|maven-compiler-plugin|3.5.1|maven-plugin)

Comment: i did try updating, several times, but for some reason I wasn't able to see a lot of artifacts.  i.e when i finally got some traction yesterday, "3.2" was the latest i saw (eclipse->add Dependency) but now I can see all the way up to "3.5", not sure why 3.5.1 isn't visible?  I assume that this was/is some sort of issue with my indexing or jboss neux repo indexing, since I haven't changed anything since...(cont'd)

Comment: I feel like I've always struggled with ensuring indices are current, usually giving up once i get just enough working that I can go back to developing.  I think i must have had one of the profiles/repo's set to include SNAPSHOTS  prior to my *cleaning*, thus why i had some local but could find them at build time.  I wasn't really looking for a specific snapshot, i was just trying to update as much as possible and hopefully not have to worry about this particular plugin's currency for a while.       Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Upon further review, i must have had another profile/repo defined earlier that had access to the SNAPSHOT versions.  After some more *careful* testing, it looks like I'm good with version "3.2", which now is the latest version shown when adding a plugin via eclipse.